# How to Show a toastr message with dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toastr

I'm using Toastr to show a popup of message in UI.

I'm sending a request to server via Ajax and in response, i'm sending a below response

```
echo json_encode(
                    array(
                            "type" => "error",
                            "message" => $error,
                            "status" => "Error While Updating!"
                         )
                );
```

I'm using the resp.type to show dynamic toastr so below is my toastr code

```
.done(function(resp)
    {
        toastr.resp.type(resp.message, resp.status,{progressBar:!0,showMethod:"slideDown",hideMethod:"slideUp",timeOut:2e3,preventDuplicates: true,positionClass: "toast-bottom-right"});
    });
```

The problem with above code is that when the code is running it throws an error message of `Uncaught TypeError: toastr.type is not a function`

Could anyone help me out what's going wrong or what might be a correct solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed `toastr.resp.type`, it is invalid and hence will throw an error.

Below code would work as you want, as far as i understand the question

```
.done(function(resp)
   {
       toastr[resp.type](resp.message, resp.status,{progressBar:!0,showMethod:"slideDown",hideMethod:"slideUp",timeOut:2e3,preventDuplicates: true,positionClass: "toast-bottom-right"});
   });
```

Please view this as a reference: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/issues/203

```
function showToast(message, timeout, type) {
      type = (typeof type === 'undefined') ? 'info' : type;
      toastr.options.timeOut = timeout;
      toastr[type](message);
  }

showToast('Hello Toastr!", 15000, 'warning');
```